# Inference based on a single observation

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, inference, small-sample

Imagine we use **machine A** to perform a task, we repeat it **1000 times** and it always takes **more then 30 min** to finish the task.
We buy a new machine (**machine B**) and in the first run it takes **29 min** to finish the exact same task. Can we claim *machine B is faster than machine A*?

What if we make the numbers more extreme: machine A was tested **1,000,000 times** and it always took more than 30 min to finish; it took machine B only **20 min** to finish the same task.

Comment: In principle it's possible that the second time you run $B,$ it takes years to finish.  Which machine would you say is "faster"?  How much would you be willing to wager on a bet you are correct, knowing *only* what you have stated in this post? :-)

Comment: Are you asking what is the meaning of "faster"? I guess we can define it as either mean or median of the two distributions.
My main question here is whether we can have any reasonable prediction based on only 1 observation.

Comment: The answer is yes--provided you make some assumptions.  For instance, in some applications it is reasonable to assume the distribution of $B$ is the same as that of $A,$ except shifted (either higher or lower).  In those cases, your minimum observation of $A$ is a *lower non-parametric prediction limit* and the *single* observation from $B$ would constitute (very) significant evidence the distribution of $B$ is shifted lower than that of $A.$  But without this initial distributional assumption, you cannot support any conclusion from a single observation.

Answer (score 2):

It boils down to what you're prepared to assume for the second case.

For example, if you assume that the shape of the distribution would remain identical but the distribution could be scaled by an unknown multiplicative constant, then you'd be able conclude that this multiplicative constant would be smaller than 1.

(Similarly if you assumed that the only change could be a shift)

However, if the two distributions might be very different in shape - or there might be both a shift and a rescaling - then you'd have little basis to rule out the situation whuber raised (the next observation from B may well be far above all the other observations).

With only one data point your conclusions are not at all robust to such assumptions as might allow you to conclude there's a reduction, but we're not in any position to tell you what is reasonable for you to assume (we don't know the circumstances).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the SD (distribution) of machine B (which is unknown at this point), extreme case:

[image]

So we cannot claim that B is faster.